# ARM template to create storage with geo replication

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-rm-template, azure-storage-account

here is the ARM template to create storage account

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "storageAccountType": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "Standard_LRS",
            "allowedValues": [
                "Standard_LRS",
                "Standard_ZRS",
                "Standard_GRS",
                "Standard_RAGRS",
                "Premium_LRS"
            ],
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Describes the storage type."
            }
        }
    },
    "resources": [
        ................
        {
            "apiVersion": "2015-06-15",
            "name": "[variables('storageName')]",
            "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
            "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
            "dependsOn": [ ],
            "tags": {
                "displayName": "storage"
            },
            "properties": {
                "accountType": "[parameters('storageAccountType')]"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

works perfectly fine, however when I'm trying to use account type Standard_RAGRS to have geo replication it returns an error:

'The storage account named ..... already exists under the subscription.'

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Is it possible you already have a storage account with that name?

Comment: Yes I have however in release definition I use Action - Create or Update so as I understand it should update it.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I follow that, what is that set on?

Comment: In VSTS Release definition there is a task "Azure Resource Group Deployment" - it has a property "Action" with possible value - Create or Update Resource Group. Other values are Select/Delete Resource Group.
I assume it should update storage to turn geo replication on but looks like that's not the case.

Comment: It could also be possible the name you are using might already be used.

Comment: I did a few more tests and it looks like I can't update existing resource, only create new storage with geo-replication

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no issue in your ARM template on the Storage Account resource.

I am able to use this template to provision storage accounts with different account types successfully.

The root cause based on your error message is because you **`already have an existing storage account name under the same resource group and same subscription`** with the one you're trying to create.

I am able to reproduce your error exactly with the same scenario above.

> message":"The storage account named 'abcstorageacct' already exists
>   under the subscription."}}

Answer (score 0):

You can update resource properties in a subsequent deployment for *some* properties but this varies by resource and property.  Unfortunately, I don't know of a good list of what's allowed.

Seems like that error could be improved...